# Могу ли я в Bootstrap форме пропустить класс form-group?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Не понимаю смысл **Bootstrap** класса **form-group** и *хочу удалить ее*. 
*Отсутствие этого класса* нечего не меняет в *отображении формы*. 
Могу ли я удалить этот *класс* вместе с *div элементом* ?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

В файле стилей *Bootstrap 4* есть строки:

```
.form-group { 
    margin-bottom: 1rem; 
}
```

Поэтому, можно уверенно сказать для чего он и как работает.
В общем говоря, этот класс используют чтобы как-то отделить поля формы между собой.

---

*Пример с этим классом:*

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</form>
```

*И пример без классов:*

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form>
  <div>
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">

  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</form>
```

Как видим, разница только в расстоянии между полями...

Answer (score 2):

Тут вопрос в том какая у тебя форма
Если одно поле то особо не влияет
Если у тебя поля горизонтально и адаптацию делать не будешь то как бы тоже

Comment: хотя можно и адаптацию сделать под каждый элемент формы не группируя их